# On IIS7, is it possible to run a php application in a virtual directory?

Tags: php, iis-7

Becasuse when I try, I get internal server error (code 500) stating that the web.config wasn't found...

Has anyone done this before and succeeded? I installed php through the web installer.

Comment: Try Process Monitor and see which/where web.config is the process looking for when you try to hit your default PHP page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it shouldn't be a problem, i have wordpress, mediawiki running off a virtual directory in IIS7.

what application is it ?
can you create a new directory on your desired location, put your php app over there and map it to a new virtual directory with a diff name ?

also check your php.ini and see if short open tag is off then switch it on:
`short_open_tag=On`

you can check your loaded PHP.ini path via php info in a web browser :
copy and paste this in a text file and save it in your web root, browse to it :

`<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Hope that helps